# Remove a certain value from string which keeps on changing

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to make a utility to generate an insert script of SQL tables along with relational table.

I got all the values in C#.

Now I want to remove the one column name and its value from the script.most probably the identity column.

For example: the string I have (which keeps on changing with table name and varies)

```
INSERT INTO Core.Customers ([customerId], [customername], [customeradress],[ordernumber])
VALUES (123, N'Rahul', N'244 LIZ MORN', 2334)
```

NOW I know I have to remove `CustomerId` (sometimes need to be replaces with `@somevariable`).

Please give me an efficient way how to retrieve `customerId` value and deleting column name and value.

I was looking for a method to find column value by column Name.

What I am doing is below - I know it's inefficient and can cause problem but for now it is working smoothly.

```
public string GetColumnValueToForDesiredColumnName(string row, TableInfo tableinfo, string NameofColumnTOfindvalueFor)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> ValueTypedictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string value = null;

    // this code is quite messy - I need some suggestion on this one
    string[] plusseperatedinsert = row.Replace("INSERT " + "[" + tableinfo.Schema + "].[" + tableinfo.TableName + "]", string.Empty).Trim().Replace("VALUES", "+").Split('+');

    string[] columnvalues = plusseperatedinsert[0].Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Trim().Split(',');

    string[] valuesfield = plusseperatedinsert[1].Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Trim().Split(',');

        for (int index = 0; index < columnvalues.Length; index++)
        {
            ValueTypedictionary.Add(columnvalues[index], valuesfield[index]);
        }

        ValueTypedictionary.TryGetValue(NameofColumnTOfindvalueFor, out value);

        return value;
    }
```

This returns 123 as value.

And then I am using

```
string.Replace("[customerId],", string.empty).Replace(123, string.empty);
```

Comment: Side note, `plusseperatedinsert[0].Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Trim().Split(',');` can be reduced to `Regex.Replace(plusseperatedinsert[0], "[\[\]()]", "").Trim().Split(',');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a special clas `InsertQuery` which stores pairs of column names with column values and then if you always need to remove or change an Id of a table you will know that it is on the first index of a list/array/whatever you use to store these pairs.

Define a method for removing this column and you are good to go.

So here is the code. You will probably change it somehow, it is just a proof of concept.

```
public class InsertQuery
{
    private class Column
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();
    private readonly string tableName;

    public InsertQuery(string tableName)
    {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public void AddColumn(string name, string value)
    {
        columns.Add(new Column { Name = name, Value = value });
    }

    public string RemoveColumnByName(string columnName)
    {
        var column = columns.First(c => c.Name == columnName);
        var value = column.Value;
        columns.Remove(column);
        return value;
    }

    public string RemoveIdColumn()
    {
        var column = columns.First();
        var value = column.Value;
        columns.RemoveAt(0);
        return value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO ");
        sb.Append(tableName);
        sb.Append(" (");

        // append first all column names and then their values

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Trust me. Building such a tool using just string operations is not quite a good idea. In time you will want to add more functionality and you will be stuck with code that can be hardly extended. Encapsulation is a way to go.